# Why apk from app bundle doesn't have launcher icon on some devices

Tags: android, bundle, android-app-bundle

We have an alpha version of our app on Google Play. Recently we started using app bundle and it seems that there is no launcher icon on some devices. We specify icon in manifest:

```
android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
```

And there is launcher_icon for each size hdpi, ldpi and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Launchers might be treated differently than other drawables. Therefore you should use mipmaps instead.

```
android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
```

The training for [screen densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#mipmap) states in this regard:

> Unlike the drawable directory, all mipmap directories are retained in the APK even if you build density-specific APKs.